# if statement for detailedViewController with tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

So I am trying to populate a tableview in a UIViewController that is pushed from another tableviewController. I know I have to write an if statement but am having trouble with this...To reiterate I guess my question is how do you populate a tableView in a detailedViewController pushed from a tableViewController? See code below to reference and I apologize in advance if I did not provide everything needed, I may be completely heading the wrong direction with this...

Thanks for any and all input!

```
/* DetaiLViewController.m file */

#import "DetaiViewController.h"
#import "RecommendationsCell.h"

/* ..........  */

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.navigationItem.title = _DetailModal[0];


   /*WHAT IS THE IF STATEMENT ???!! */
       if ([self.navigationItem.title isEqualToString: @"London, United Kingdom"]) {

       DetailedImages.image = /* HERE IS AN ARRAY OF London IMAGES to DISPLAY ON DETAILEDVIEWCONTROLLER */

    IF....
       DetailedImages.image = /* HERE IS AN ARRAY OF LONDON IMAGES to DISPLAY ON DETAILEDVIEWCONTROLLER */

    IF....
       DetailedImages.image = /* HERE IS AN ARRAY OF BERLIN IMAGES to DISPLAY ON DETAILEDVIEWCONTROLLER */

    IF...
DetailedImages.image = /* HERE IS AN ARRAY OF PERTH IMAGES to DISPLAY ON DETAILEDVIEWCONTROLLER */

    IF...
THE REMAINING ARRAYS FOR EACH CELL FROM TABLEVIEWCONTROLLER ETC.......
                                 ];
    }



/* HERE IS ARRAY FROM TABLEVIEWCONTROLLER THAT PUSHES TO DETAILEDVIEWCONTROLLER */
/*    _Images = @[@"london.jpeg",

                @"berlin.jpeg",

                @"perth.jpeg",

                @"beijing.jpeg",

                @"Madrid-26512.jpg",

                @"barcelona.jpeg",

                @"norway1_2141015b.jpg",

                @"sweden.jpeg",]; */


/* HERE IS ARRAY FROM TABLEVIEWCONTROLLER THAT PUSHES TO DETAILEDVIEWCONTROLLER */
 /*   _Title = @[@"London, United Kingdom",

               @"Berlin, Germany",

               @"Perth, Australia",

               @"Beijing, China",

               @"Madrid, Spain",

               @"Barcelona, Spain",

               @"Oslo, Norway",

               @"Denmark, Sweden",]; */

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _Title.count;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RecommendationsCell";
    RecommendationsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];    

    // Configure the cell...    

    int row = [indexPath row];

    cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
    //cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];
    cell.ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_Images[row]];

    return cell;
}




/* DetailedViewController.h file */

@interface DetaiViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *DetailedImages;
}

//@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Description;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Images;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *DetailModal;

@end



/* DetailedViewController Cell.h file */

@interface RecommendationsCell : UITableViewCell 

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ThumbImage;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *DescriptionLabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DetailedImages;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would NOT base your decision on the navigation title. Pass the title to your detail view control. Add something like this to DetailViewController.h

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedTitle;

In your if statement, check for that value and do your conditional.

A better solution would be to create objects that represent your data and pass that to your detail view controller. This would eliminate your conditionals and make the code easier to add additional Titles.

I would have an object that has a NSString for the title and an NSArray for the images to show for that location. Then on your parent view controller, you would have an NSArray that has each of those objects and that would be your table data source.

If you wanted to separate it even more, you could create a class that manages your data for you, for instance a LocationRepository and you can have a method that creates the array and populates your data, this way any view controller can get that data.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Creating objects makes sense. So just to clarify, if my tableViewController had 8 cells I would create 8 NSObject classes (the titles)...and then create instances for each object with the set of NSArray images in the implementation file of the parent view controller? Not to be pushy but perhaps a quick code sample may help...I am obviously a beginner. Thanks again!

Comment: Your table cell count will depend on the number of items in your array, so yes if you have 8 objects in your array, you will have 8 cells. What code do you need help on?

Answer (score 0):

if statement is to give some condition for code between { }. In your case when your navigationItem.title will be "London, United Kingdom" all code in { } will be processed. You can give more condition like this:

```
if ([self.navigationItem.title isEqualToString: @"London, United Kingdom"]) {
    //do this
   DetailedImages.image = /* HERE IS AN ARRAY OF London IMAGES to DISPLAY ON DETAILEDVIEWCONTROLLER */
   } else if ([self.navigationItem.title isEqualToString: @"Berlin, Germany"]){
    //or do this
   DetailedImages.image = /* HERE IS AN ARRAY OF LONDON IMAGES to DISPLAY ON DETAILEDVIEWCONTROLLER */
   } else {  
 ..........    // if no condition passed do that
   }
```

Hope it help answer your question about if statement.

To your populate problem. In your code is some _Title.count for numberOfRowsInSection. I don't know what kind of array is that, but:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RecommendationsCell";
RecommendationsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];    

Title * title = [self.title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   
Images *image = [self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.TitleLabel.text = title;
//cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];
cell.ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image];

return cell;
```

}